# Substracting attributes of different layers

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, virtual-layer

Can I subtract two attributes belonging  to two different layers? In this case these would be two polygons holding DEPTH attribute (Depth1 - Depth2).
 
Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: You could `join attributes by location` and then perform the substraction on the joined layer. Or you could create a virtual layer.

Comment: How are the polygons related, do they share some common attribute, do they overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to use a virtual layer. Let's suppose you have two layers `polygon_1` and `polygon_2` with fields and values as follows:

[image]

Go to `Menu Layer / Create layer / New Virtual Layer…` and paste this query:

```
SELECT p1.fid, depth_1-depth_2 as difference, p1.geometry
FROM polygon_1 as p1, polygon_2 as p2
where p1.fid = p2.fid
```

The features are connected with their common `fid`. You not not state how the features should be connected, so I guess you have a common identifier in your data. However, you can adapt this to your needs. The attributes table of the new virtual layer looks like this, containing a newly calculated column for the difference `depth_1 - depth_2`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use QGIS expressions. If you are in the attribute table of a layer, open the field calculator and paste the following expression (adapting it to the names of your layers/fields) to get a value from an attribute field of another layer:

```
attribute (
    get_feature_by_id (
        'Polygon_2', 
        $id
    ), 
    'depth_2'
)
```

Let's suppose you have two layers:

1. Polygon_1 with attribute `depth_1` (on this layer, you open the field calculator)
2. Polygon_2  with attribute `depth_2` (this is the value you want to get in the other layer)

You can get the value from one layer to the other one if they have a common field that they can be connected with - here: the same `id`. Of course, it works also with other conditions. But since in your question you have not stated how the features of the two layers should be related, I suppose for demonstration purpose that they are connected by a commond id. If not, change the expression accordingly.

With the expression above, for each feature on `Polygon_1`, you get the according value (of the feature with the same id) from `Polygon_2`, namely value of field `depth_2`. You can use this to copy values from `Polygon_2` to `Polygon_1`. If you add `"depth_1"` - before the above expression, you get the difference `depth_1`  - `depth_2` (what you want), see the screenshot:

[image]